# htaccess: redirect old asp url strings

Tags: .htaccess

I have a client we built a new site for and are trying to redirect his old urls to point to the new site. The problem is they are long strings and my current solution is not working correctly. This is what I currently have:

```
Redirect 301 /frameset.asp?page=services.htm http://domain.com/
```

this results in the user being sent to:

```
http://domain.com/.asp?page=services.htm
```

Last but not least is there a wildcard solution?

FROM THE ACCEPTED ANSWER: (Just so this is documented for the next guy, yhis is what i ended up using.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /frameset\.asp\?page=* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/? [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not redirect query strings using a Redirect directiv, you have to use mod-rewrite
Try :

```
 RewriteEngine on



 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /frameset\.asp\?page=services\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/? [L,R]
```